# Не работает скрипт который возвращает факториал (js)

Tags: javascript

Задача – написать функцию factorial(n) , которая возвращает
факториал числа n! , используя рекурсивный вызов.

Написал такой скрипт

```
function factorial(n){
        var sum = n;
        for(var i=1; i<n; i++){
            return sum*=i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    alert(factorial(5));
```

По идеи он должен вывести число 120.Но выводит просто 5. Не понимаю в чем проблема. П.с. мне нужен цикличный вызов а не рекурсивный.

Comment: первый return завершает цикл

Comment: убрал,заработало.Но не понимаю почему return завершает цикл? Если у меня n=5 и i<n то цикл должен продолжаться или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: А все понял.Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У тебя в цикле присутствует лишний `return` . То есть у тебя цикл выполняется один раз(5 умножается на 1) и это значение возвращается. Убери `return` и все получится.

Answer (score 2):

У вас и рекурсивного вызова как такого и не имеется.
`factorial(n)` должена вызывать саму себя внутри себя, что бы это считалось рекурсией. 
В вашем случае должно быть так:

```
function factorial(n){
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n*factorial(n-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного офф-топ, но верно подмечено.